# Why did I lose consecutive status?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

> **Possible duplicate:**
>
> [Consecutive Day count reset this morning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61007/consecutive-day-count-reset-this-morning) on meta.stackoverflow.com

According to my user page, I only have one day consecutive, but looking at this answer:

[Which StarCraft 2 maps are played most often?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7233/which-starcraft-2-maps-are-played-most-often/7268#7268)

It shows that I answered the question yesterday, and that I commented today. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

[All SE sites calculate days based on GMT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24884/what-are-the-exact-requirements-for-the-woot-enthusiast-badge). If you live in a different time zone, it's possible you logged in early one day and late the day after, but in terms of GMT a whole day passed in-between.

If you look at the exact times in which you answered and commented:

```
Answered  2010-09-11 21:25:53Z
Commented 2010-09-13 03:33:50Z
```

You can see that you have indeed missed a day.

Comment: StackExchange also has the nasty byproduct that you must view at least one question page to get recorded.  Visiting the main page or your own profile page *does not count*.  This is due to a feature in Safari... I'll have to look up the exact reason Jeff quoted me in my email.

Comment: @Powerlord: "a feature in safari" sounds like it is referring to [top sites](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/02/safari-4-focus-top-sites-browser-in-a-nutshell.ars). If you visit gaming.SE a lot, safari will try to reload the page and show you a thumbnail each time you open a new tab. This creates 'visits' when you are not actually reading anything on the site. Opera and Chrome have something similar.

Comment: @Kaestur: The exact quote was 'This is necessary because of Safari 4+ "wall of sites" behavior, where it ambiently loads the homepage of every site you regularly visit when you launch the browser.'

Comment: @Powerlord: Yep, that's same the feature I described. "top sites" and "quick launch" are more common names for it.